# Select edge attributes and also expand/populate in and out in waterline

Tags: sails.js, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

How can I populate in and out of edges in waterline
i am using waterline-oreintdb adopter

here is my query

```
select *,out.* from sellings // selling is edge class
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try asking this in the waterline-orientdb repo as well

Comment: Hi @Travis Webb How can I ask to waterline-orientdb repo ?

Comment: @9me, here's how: https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#discussion

Comment: thanks Sir. i created new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like an OrientDB question than an waterline one. One option would be to use a fetch plan ([OrientDB Docs](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/Fetching-Strategies.html)):

```
select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in:1 out:1') from selling
```

Comment: There is no waterline solution for this ?

Comment: Potentially [many-to-many through associations](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md#many-to-many-through-associations) but those are not officially released yet.

Comment: Hi @Dário using ``` select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in:1 out:1') from selling ``` I am just getting ids list. Is there any way to fetch records as well ? Thanks you.

Comment: From that you'll probably need to use `expand()`: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#expand